# SVG <use> sizing and placement different in Safari than Firefox & Chrome

Tags: svg

After defining a `<symbol>` in an SVG `<defs>` section upon `<use>` it doesn't get placed or scaled properly in Safari but does in Firefox and Chrome.

The following code displays two small filled circles over each other centered in a box using Firefox and Chrome. The circle from the `<use>` is large and misplaced with Safari.

```
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs>
        <symbol id="mark" width="8" height="8" viewBox="0 0 8 8">
            <circle cx="4" cy="4" r="4"/>
        </symbol>
    </defs>
    <g>
        <use href="#mark" x="46" y="46" fill="black"/>
        <circle href="#mark" cx="50" cy="50" r="2" stroke="none" fill="red"/>
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" stroke="red" fill="none"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

What part of the viewbox and sizing am I missing?

Safari output:

[image: Safari]

Firefox output:

[image: Firefox]

Comment: `width`and `height` are to be defined on the `<use>` element, not the `<symbol>`. Otherwise, they are set to 100% - and that makes the difference: in absence of `width`and `height` on the root, Safari sets a wrong size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @ccprog said, size needs to be defined in the `<use>` element. This code works across all three browsers:

```
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs>
        <symbol id="mark" viewBox="0 0 8 8">
            <circle cx="4" cy="4" r="4"/>
        </symbol>
    </defs>
    <g>
        <use href="#mark" width="8" height="8" x="46" y="46" fill="black"/>
        <circle href="#mark" cx="50" cy="50" r="2" stroke="none" fill="red"/>
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" stroke="red" fill="none"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```